# create a path between multiple pin as a route on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, dictionary, mkmapview

i have three latitude and longitude for three different location, i want to draw a paths between all point . for example if i have A,B and C locations then i want connect A with B and B with C and C with A.

i have a iphone application in which i used mapkit framework,suppose user start travel from A point then reached on B and end the travel on C point. i want to draw a path between all three point. A to B, B To C and C

Comment: (MKDirectionsRequest)[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirectionsRequest_class/Reference/Reference.html]

Comment: Not clear what you want to do and in which technology you want to do that

Comment: i have a iphone application in which i used mapkit framework,suppose user start travel from A point then reached on B and end the travel on C point. i want to draw a path between all three point. A to B, B To C and C to A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think might be this url helps to you

https://github.com/kadirpekel/MapWithRoutes

http://mobileappdeve.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-add-annotation-on-mapview-ios.html